# flask-socketio in kubernetes, ingress and multiple replicas

Tags: kubernetes, flask, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, flask-socketio

i'm running a flask-socketio behind an ingress.
here's the config:

```
socketio = SocketIO(app, message_queue='redis://redis-server.domain:6379')
```

in the dockerfile, it runs like so:

```
CMD ["gunicorn", "-k", "geventwebsocket.gunicorn.workers.GeventWebSocketWorker", "-w", "4", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:2731", "app:app"]
```

and the ingress is configured like this:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-ssl-passthrough: "true"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: "route"
```

i also tried replacing "cookie" with "ip_hash"

whenever i add a second replica pod, it starts returning error 400, as if it contacts the pods interchangeably, and not sticking to the same server, thus breaking the socket.

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, it should have worked but try this **.spec.sessionAffinity**

Set it to **service**

`.spec.sessionAffinity` value will be **ClientIP**

**Service** to **POD** sticky session

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: test-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: test-app
  ports:
  - name: http
    protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort: 80
  sessionAffinity: ClientIP
```

Answer (score 2):

i've selected Harsh Manvar's ansewer as the correct one, but adding details for future reference:

in the service, sessionAffinity: ClientIP as suggested.

the Run command in dockerfile:

```
CMD ["gunicorn", "-k", "geventwebsocket.gunicorn.workers.GeventWebSocketWorker", "-w", "1", "--bind", "0.0.0.0:6138", "--timeout", "180", "app:app"]
```

the requirements.txt:

```
gunicorn
simple-websocket
gevent-websocket
gevent
```

the socketio:

```
socketio = SocketIO(app, message_queue='redis://redis-service.redis:6379')
```

added to ingress:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-ssl-passthrough: "true"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/add-base-url: "true"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: "route"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/websocket-services: service-name
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-expires: "172800"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-max-age: "172800"
```